# How to ignore hyphens in mongodb docs values

Tags: mongodb

Hi my problem is that I have a collection with data, in the data I have values string with hyphens between words
example: "item:'e-commerce'"

my question is if there any options to set mongo to ignore the hyphens when I query string,
example to query: value to search "e commerce" and the result should be "item:'e-commerce'", the worst solution is to do Normalization to the collections without hyphens.

Comment: if you are using mongoose, then try to use "validate" and "pre" functions of model object.

Comment: If you have an inconsistent mix between `e-commerce` and `ecommerce`, this is just bad data that should be normalized and sanitized before it enters the database. Otherwise, you'll be dealing with expensive pre-processing every time you need to query your data.

Answer (score 0):

Normalizing this field sounds like the way to go here.

Another (likely bad) tack would be using a [collation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/collation/) that set `alternate` to `"shifted"` so that you ignore all whitespace & punctuation while doing comparisons.